# In android, is it possible to get the current http url when the youtube app is playing video?

Tags: android, http, url

My goal is to create an app that can know the name of the current video playing in youtube app in android. I have found it is impossible(possible?). So maybe there is a way for me to know the current video's url ( then maybe I can obtain the video id from the url).
Is it possible? I have check the youtube process's proc folder, but I didn't find such information. Because the youtube app doesn't use an browser, is it possible for me to know such information? thx:>

Comment: @TryTryAgain What log file? You mean the log file of youtube? Or the system log?

Comment: @TryTryAgain   I have found there is no log file in android. The only choice seems to  be use logcat. However , the output doesn't contain the url information if you use the youtube app ( It does show if you use the brower):<

Comment: You're right, sorry. I guess that information is not available.